# Microservices: Simultaneous cache updates

Tags: caching, microservices, hazelcast

I am developing a microservice. This MS will be deployed to docker containers and will be monitored by Kubernetes. I have to implement a caching solution using hazelcast distributed cache. My requirements are:

- Preload the cache on startup of this microservice. For around 3000 stores I have to fetch two specific attributes and cache them.
- Every 24 hours refresh the cache.

I implemented Spring @EventListener and on startup to make a database call for the 2 attributes and do a @CachePut and store them in Cache.

I also have a Spring scheduler with cron expression to refresh cache at every 6 AM in morning.

So far so good.

But what I did not realize that in clustered environment - 10-15 instances of my microservice will be in action and will try to do above 2 steps almost simultaneously - thus creating a stampede effect on my database and cache. Does anyone know what to do in this scenario? Is there any good design or even average one which I can follow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking to use Hazelcast provided Loading and Storing Persistent Data mechanism that allows 2 options for writing: *Write-through* and *write-behind* and *read-through* for loading data into the cache.

Look for **MapLoader** and its methods, that will let you warm-up/preload your cluster and you have the freedom to do that with your own implementation.

Check for more details: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data